# Input-output arguments vs. no arguments with side-effects

Tags: parameters, arguments, coding-style

Is it better to write methods that take no arguments and have side-effects, changing the object state, or one-argument methods taking an argument and processing it? If the second alternative is preferable, is it better to return the input argument explicitly or just process it, since the caller is supposed to have a reference to it.

To be more precise: I am processing XML and having read the first chapters of the [Clean Code book](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/software-engineering-and-development/agile-development/9780136083238) I am trying to split the Big Processing method into many small ones, so this method can be read like a story, in the lines of :

```
cleanHeader();

extractMetaInfo();

appendStuff();
```

and so on, where these methods all operate on the XML document stored as member.

IMHO, the best practices of reducing the parameter count vs. having no side effects seem to contradict each other here. Would it be better to write as follows?

```
doc = cleanHeader(doc);

doc = extractMetaInfo(doc);

doc = appendStuff(doc);
```

Is there a definite "right" on that issue? How much more context would a definite answer depend on? Or is there a third alternative i did not think about?

EDIT : found a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3692600/one-function-argument-or-instance-variable-clean-code-book) with contradictory answers. Care to elaborate?

Comment: Side-effects is the mother of all evil. Not even goto gets close.

Comment: thank you, leppie. that was pretty unambiguous :) and seems very plausible. could you please provide a link/other info to support your judgment? would it be better to return the original argument or to change it "function-style",i.e. implicitly?

Comment: I strongly recommend to read the book: "Effective Java" by Joshua Bloch - He votes in this specific question for opposite (use parameter). In general Bloch prefere stateless classes for different reasons (performance and usability). @kostja - you could use it as reference for leppie's statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your algothimen could be used by several threads in parallel then the way recommended in the clean code book (statfull but whithout arguments) would not work. In this case you must use the parameter way!

Comment: that's a good reason. thank you, Ralph. And thanks again for the book ref.

Answer (score 0):

I would argue this from an OO design perspective. If you have a bunch of methods that operate on the same object like doc, then you probably need a class that wraps that object and encapsulates the behavior into a bigProcessingMethod() that calls the smaller processing methods it you want to break the task down further.

public class DocUtil
{
    private String doc;

```
public DocUtil(String doc)
{
     this.doc = doc;
}

public bigProcessingMethod()
{
     cleanHeader(doc);

 extractMetaInfo(doc);

 appendStuff(doc);

}
```

//etc.
}

I misunderstood your question. I didn't realize you were already inside of a wrapper class like DocUtil.

Whether you pass the doc variable explicitly to each of the processing methods or not, you're doing work on the same object at the same memory location. The only reason I'd pass it each time is to be explicit that these are methods that work on the variable doc.

It's up to you.

Comment: Thanky you, user381091. Im not quite sure what you're trying to point out. My question is about implicit vs explicit state change of this very wrapper you proposed. I would like to see some rationale for either possibility considering the application of best practices.